# Capture every instance of a pattern in a string using regex and PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to capture all instances that matches the pattern in a string.

For example, the pattern to match is

> MM/YYYY

and the string is

> 03/201408/201511/201203/201408/201511/201203/201408/201511/2012

Currently, I have this regex pattern

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{4}
```

but it's not matching all the dates with MM/YYYY format.

Comment: [It looks working](https://regex101.com/r/xD7oF2/1). See [this demo](http://ideone.com/6pTeXH), too. Please specify what trouble you have with it.

Comment: as @WiktorStribiżew said, it's working, what's the code you're using ?

Comment: What's the PHP usage? If you have `/` as the delimiter that will fail..

Comment: it's working now. thanks Wiktor for the demo. I did not put ?: in the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: It would work even without `?:` - http://ideone.com/KEExos. I do not think it is an excuse. The capturing group is just redundant, but it does not spoil or ruin anything. You only need Group 0 (match value). Please explain your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is with the regex usage in PHP.

Here is how you can get these substrings:

```
$re = '~(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{4}~'; 
$str = "03/201408/201511/201203/201408/201511/201203/201408/201511/2012"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/6pTeXH)

I just suggest using a non-capturing group in order not to clutter the results  with unnecessary values.